# What is the firs sci-fi work a PBY Catalina seaplane was used in?

Tags: history-of, transportation

Would like to know what was the first sci-fi work in any medium (books, comics, movies, TV series) that had a [PBY Catalina seaplane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consolidated_PBY_Catalina) in it.
It does not matter if the type of the plane was clearly stated or not.

Am asking because I would like to use one on something am writing.
Just because it's a beautiful plane.

[image]

Comment: With that said, and anticipating the edit, I wonder if Clive Cussler's Dirk Pitt novels (several of which have involved slightly science-fictional technology) are considered on topic here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search on "pby catalina in fiction" leads to a [Wikipedia talk page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Consolidated_PBY_Catalina#The_PBY_in_fiction) that indicates that Greg Bear's novel [Dinosaur Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinosaur_Summer) has a PBY in it. I don't have the book at hand to double check.